# How to use departure_time on google distance matrix api

Tags: google-distancematrix-api

In reading the documentation https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro  the `departure_time` must be set in the future and based on `January 1, 1970 UTC 00:00:00`. This tells me that if I run a Distance Matrix API request during my working day in CT time zone I need to calculate the number of seconds from `1/1/1970 00:00:00 UTC` to some future time say `03:00:00` on tomorrow morning for `UTC-6` (CT time).  Example: today is `5/31/2017`, the number of seconds calculated should be the number of seconds between `1/1/1970 00:00:00` and `1/1/2017 03:00:00` – 6 hours (`1496286000 – 360 = 1496285640`) I insert `departure_time=1496285640` . Will someone who has successfully used this optional parameter please confirm.

Comment: Facing the same dilemma. Seems to be departure time can be in local to compare against 1/1/1970 00:00:00 UTC. Meaning if my time is UTC + 8, and I'm looking for duration at 9 am; I calculate departure as 10/04/2018 09:00:00 - 01/01/1970 00:00:00. 
Though the result given in this API is not in accordance with the Google Map distance/duration.

Comment: You shared an easier way to look at calculating the time and, from what I can tell, it appears to work. Yes the API documentation could be a bit better.  Thank you.